# Tips for Prime Factorization of a Given Large Interger

Tags: number-theory

This may be a slightly silly question, but are there any tips for prime factorization when slight hints are given?

For example, if you were not possesed of pen, paper, or calculator, and somebody asked you to prime factor $294020099$ with the three hints given below, is it possible there are some ways that you could do it within a short amount of time?

Hint $1$.The prime factors are between $500$ and $900$

Hint $2$.The number $294020099$ has three prime factors

Hint $3$.The sum of all prime factors are equal to $2049$.

While I am aware that there are some computer algorithims, actually doing them in your head seemed difficult. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use various divisibility tricks to attempt to find particular small factors, for example ends with an even digit $\implies$ even, sum of digits divisible by $3$ $\implies$ number is divisible by $3$, etc. But if it's the product of three large primes, as above, this won't help.

Comment: +1 for a very interesting question IMO. In the answer that I gave below, you still need to check if $a+b+c=2049$ for approximately $26^3$ different combinations of $a$, $b$ and $c$. So I suspect that there might be a better solution, which I would be happy to see in case anyone comes up with anything.

Comment: @barakmanos Thank you. This problem, I might add was largely inspired by a story where a man asks someone to prime factor $7262011$. The person thought for a moment, then said $191 \times 193 \times 197$. When the man asked the person how he managed it, he claimed that it was intuition. I was wondering if there were actually ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ denote the three prime factors.

Each prime factor must end with either $1$, $3$, $7$ or $9$.

In addition, each one of the following two conditions must hold:

- $a\times b\times c\equiv9\pmod{10}$
- $a   +   b   +   c\equiv9\pmod{10}$

A quick check reveals that WLOG:

- $a\equiv3\pmod{10}$
- $b\equiv7\pmod{10}$
- $c\equiv9\pmod{10}$

So the general algorithm would be:

- Choose $a$ from the following lists:

  - $503,533,563,\dots,833,863,893$
  - $523,553,583,\dots,823,853,883$
- Choose $b$ from the following lists:

  - $517,547,577,\dots,817,847,877$
  - $527,557,587,\dots,827,857,887$
- Choose $c$ from the following lists:

  - $509,539,569,\dots,839,869,899$
  - $529,559,589,\dots,829,859,889$
- If $a+b+c=2049$, then check if $a\times b\times c=294020099$

Answer (score 1):

Without a pen and a paper it is really hard; but one could solve it by hand, without a computer as follows. First we try
to find the smallest divisor $d$ of $294020099$ with $d\ge 500$. One would quickly see that $d=503$, because the division by $501$ leaves a remainder, and $500$, $502$ are even, hence impossible.
 Then one had to show that $503$ is indeed prime, and consider the cofactor $584533$. Now it gets harder, but not impossible.

Comment: Once you've found the first factor, it's actually easy to use hint 3 to factor the chunk $584533$ that you're left with; from $p\cdot q=584533$ and $p+q=2049-503=1546$ the quadratic formula will get you both of $p$ and $q$ quickly by just taking a square root (which _can_ be done easily by hand).

Comment: Yes, thank you Steven.

Comment: I guess from this answers that there are no methods for avoiding complex calculation.

Comment: @ChadShin In general there is no way around the standard factorization algorithms. In special cases, however, one can somtimes do something. However, this is not too interesting.